# Linux systemd - how does systemd resolve dependency loop

Tags: linux, process, dependencies, centos7, systemd

I'm trying to figure out how does systemd in CentOS 7 deals with dependency loop. For example:

```
[unit A]
After=unit B
```

and the second

```
[unit B]
After=unit A
```

System should detect loop, but what algorithm is used and how does it work? I've searched through network but nobody describes HOW does it work only that IT WORKS by making After or Before statement.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions specific to `systemd` are more appropriate to be asked on http://serverfault.com, http://unix.stackexchange.com or if they are Ubuntu-specific http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

systemd does not "resolve" dependency loops. It breaks them arbitrarily (as far as I know) and goes on. Dependency loops are not valid in the systemd configuration and should be resolved by the administrator as they will not be auto-resolved.

See also: [Generic methodology to debug ordering cycles in systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193714/generic-methodology-to-debug-ordering-cycles-in-systemd)